# fastAPI pydantic parsing Union[list,dict] error

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

When I use `fastapi` to validate a post request body, and one parameter can either be a dict or a list of dicts. But when this parameter is a list of mutiple dicts, when I use `Union[dict, list]` parsing error.

The following is my code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Any, Optional, Union

class NoticeDagTask(BaseModel):
    next_msg: Union[dict, list]
    success_without_msg: bool = False 

......

async def notice_next(notice_node: NoticeDagTask, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    logger.info(f"request to notice_next with {notice_node=}")
    ppid = notice_node.ppid
    pid = notice_node.pid
    node = notice_node.node
    next_msg = notice_node.next_msg
```

An example request body:

```py
next_msg = [{"key1": {"i_key1": 1}}, {"key2": {"i_key2": 2}},]
```

When I change the `next_msg` to `Any`, it can parsing correctly. How do I fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what if you fill in the generic args of `list` and `dict`, like e.g. `list[dict[str, dict[str, int]]]`?